# NullReferenceException while calling WebMethod

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I have the following problem;

My console app is running on the server and all I want to do is control it over ASP.NET Web Service.

I added new ASP.NET Web Service project to my Solution where my main console app and added reference to it.

The problem is every time WebMethod calls function from console app, i get the nullreferenceexception. Even if I try to use static classes or singletons; every object is null, although my console app is running absolutely correctly.

Should I change some permisions setting or something?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may start by showing your code (service **and** client preferably).

Comment: If you suspect permissions to be the issue try to run the two processes with local admin rights or as local admins. If it runs then without any other modification chances are it's permissions related.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to do here - do you want to call web service from console app or do you want to administer your console app using web service API?

Comment: @VinayC
i want to administer my console app using web service api.

@John
i dont think that the system admin-permissions are the issue, because all my visual studios are running with admin rights.

@Darin
the code is pretty complicated; i'm trying to construct some working shortcut of it. i will post it here in the next minutes.

Comment: The web service and asp.net is running with permission from service and pool, and not by administrator rights of vs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments - your console app needs to expose API to administer it. Now this can be possible by using WCF Web Services where your console app needs to host the WCF Services. Controlling console app from ASP.NET web services would be difficult because ASP.NET web services would be hosted in different process/AppDomain (by IIS) - so they somehow need to talk console app process. This across process talk is possible in .NET using remoting or WCF. So its better to use directly WCF to provide web based API (instead of using ASP.NET web services).
Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) article to start with creating simple WCF service and hosting it in console.